# Tracking Parse notification consumption

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Recently we switched our push notification system over to Parse.com, but I'm having ridiculous trouble integrating our client on several ends.

These are the two requirements, yet it seems impossible to implement them together:

1. There are several different types of notifications (different sounds based on type, or icons, etc.) that need to be used depending on the state of the client and the notification received. Therefor I need the option of a custom `NotificationBuilder`.
2. I need to track the consumption of the notification.

Their documentation states that if you want to handle everything yourself, all you have to do is add one line when the internal Parse `OPEN` event is broadcasted:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

Ha! If only that worked.

By preventing the internal `Parse` helper from receiving the `RECEIVE` event (by overriding the `onPushReceive()` method of the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`), it appears to remove any link between the data pushed to the device and the Parse service running on it (which makes sense why that would be, since it never reached the starting point in the first place). And no, calling the super version is not an option, as it would cause Parse to display its version of a notification since there will be an alert/title key that I have no control over.

I figured, what the hell, might as well try to put the tracking method call in the `Activity` that is called by the popup (whose Intent does contain all the data originally passed to it). Still, no effect, reaffirming my belief that intercepting the event is preventing the local `Parse` system from knowing there's a notification to consume, therefor preventing its consumption from being tracked.

So, the question is, does anyone know how to get Parse to use a custom NotificationBuilder so that the events it requires can actually be triggered correctly, allowing me to actually track notification consumption?

Or any kind of solution that enables me to use a custom notification, while still triggering the appropriate events to be tracked?

Possibly some way to save the `push_hash` and manually send the API call to whatever endpoint handles consumption?

Quite literally pulled some hair out over this one today and would appreciate any help I can get...

Thanks, everyone!